# Break error while creating a calendar

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Pic of error]

Have break error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode==0x0). No errors with build, just when run, have a break

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let calendars = self.calendars {
        return calendars.count
    }
    return 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
```

**//error happens here**

```
    if self.calendars != nil {
    let calendarName = self.calendars?[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].title
        cell.textLabel?.text = calendarName
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Unknown Calendar Name"
    }
    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let addCalendarVC = destinationVC.viewControllers[0] as! AddCalendarViewController
    addCalendarVC.delegate = self
}
func calendarDidAdd() {
    self.loadCalendars()
    self.refreshTableView()
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
```

You are unwrapping an optional value which might be `nil` in the first place. Cell might not have been created yet especially if you haven't registered the cell's class with that identifier so it'll crash first time table tries to populate the cell. You should first check if cell is `nil`:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
if cell == nil {
  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate red flag I see is here:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
```

When dequeueing reusable cells, I like to wrap them in guard statements, so my app doesn't crash. It also tells me a bit more information when something does go wrong:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") else {
    print("couldn't dequeue a reusable cell for identifier Cell in \(#function)")
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

This crash could be for a few reasons. You may have forgotten to register the reuse identifier, but if you're using storyboards this is handled for you. There may simply be a typo or you forgot to enter a reuse identifier for that cell.

Comment: The crash likely indicates the cell class was never registered in the first place.

Comment: Returning a raw `UITableViewCell()` doesn't make sense because in `cellForRowAt`, you are expected to create and return a fully configured cell that will be reused over and over again.

Comment: @ozgur what kind of error handling do you suggest if the reuse identifier is invalid?

Comment: @ForestKunecke There is no such thing like "invalid reuse identifier" if you haven't registered cell with that identifier in the first place. First call to `dequeueReusableCell` will always return `nil`. However, what I am saying is returning a `UITableViewCell()` is not the right way when that happens.

Comment: @ozgur Interesting. I have been reading through [Apple's documentation on the method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifie) and it looks like it actually returns `nil` only when a nib/class hasn't been registered with that identifier or if no cell is available for reuse. What do you think is the best practice if the reuse identifier has not been registered? Is there a way I can improve what I'm doing?

Comment: I put an image of the coding

Comment: @ozgur only did your answer and it worked, Thank you